# RavenDB full-text search

Tags: search, ravendb, full-text-search

Can you please tell how to perform simple full-text search in **RavenDb**. The database is stored document: *Movie {Name = "Pirates of the Carribean"}*. I wish that this document was found on the search phrase "Pirates Carribean" or any other combination of words.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are worrying about isn't anything to do with full text - by default Lucene works on an OR basis and what you want is an AND

If I were you I'd do

```
 String[] terms = searchTerm.Split(" "); // Or whatever the string.split method is
```

and

```
  .Where("Name:(" + String.Join(" AND ", terms) + ")");
```

Your index should look something like

```
 public class Movie_ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask
 {
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition()
    {
        return new IndexDefinitionBuilder<Movie>
                   {
                       Map = movies => from movie in movies
                                        select new { movie.Name, market.Id },

                       Indexes =
                           {
                               {x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed}
                           }
                   }
            .ToIndexDefinition(DocumentStore.Conventions);
    }
```

You don't need storage, you're not requesting the data from lucene directly at any time. You might not even want an index (You might actually want FieldIndexing.Analyzed, and might get away with just using dynamic queries here)

Up to you though.

Comment: Or searchTerm.Replace(" ", " AND "), although perhaps you might wish to be wary of empty entries and all that.

Comment: Is the markets/market text left over from a copy paste by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I used the other question as an example

Comment: Where movies variable come from?

Answer (score 16):

Boris,
Rob's answer has the right index, but it is a bit awkward for querying. You can do that using:

```
 session.Query<Movie, Movie_ByName>()
         .Search(x=>x.Name, searchTerms)
         .ToList()
```

That will

Comment: @RonnieOverby And that was the moment he was eaten by a bear.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I acheived an "ANDing" term search.

First, make sure that your field is indexed and analyzed:

```
public class MyIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocument>
{
    public MyIndex()
    {
        Map = docs => from d in docs
                      select new { d.MyTextField  };

        Index(x => x.MyTextField, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

Then query from the client:

```
   var query = session.Query<MyDocument, MyIndex>();

    query = theSearchText
                .Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Aggregate(query, (q, term) =>
                     q.Search(x => x.MyTextField, term, options: SearchOptions.And));
```