# IRavenQueryable<T> for both space-splitted search-terms and complete search-string as whole

Tags: c#, search, full-text-search, ravendb, iqueryable

In our own `RavenQueryableExtensions` class we have the following method:

```
public static IRavenQueryable<T> SearchMultiple<T>(this IRavenQueryable<T> self,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> fieldSelector, string queries,
    decimal boost = 1, SearchOptions options = SearchOptions.Or)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(queries)) throw new ArgumentNullException("queries");


    // All gabs of more than a single space (like tabs, two spaces, etc.)
    // are reduced to a single space
    var newQueries = Regex.Replace(queries, @"\s{2,}", " ");

    //newQueries = SyncShared.ReplacePostcode(newQueries); // not important for this question

    // The complete search-string is splitted into seperated search-terms
    var searchValues = newQueries.Split(' ');


    return self.SearchMultiple(fieldSelector, searchValues, boost, options);
}

public static IRavenQueryable<T> SearchMultiple<T>(this IRavenQueryable<T> self,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> fieldSelector, IEnumerable<string> queries,
    decimal boost = 1, SearchOptions options = SearchOptions.Or)
{
    if (queries == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("queries");

    return queries.Aggregate(self, (current, query) => current.Search(fieldSelector, query + "* ", boost, options, EscapeQueryOptions.AllowPostfixWildcard));
}
```

Which creates a search-query with all the loose search-terms in the searchValues-array and the `SearchOptions` parameter. If this would always be `SearchOptions.Or`, I could just add the complete search-string to this array and everything would be fine, but since we also use `SearchOptions.And` as parameter sometimes, I'm having a problem.

What I want is either all results that match all individual Search-terms combined OR the complete search-term as a whole.

For example: Lets say I have the following search term: `"This is a search term"`

- Right now we will get the following Query: `"This" AND "is" AND "a" AND "search" AND "term"`
- What I want instead however is: `("This" AND "is" AND "a" AND "search" AND "term") OR "This is a search term"`

The problem mainly lies in the fact that we use virtual and dynamic queries for multiple classes, otherwise we could most likely just add the complete Search-term to the Map-Index like in [this SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13999848/1682559).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need to bother.

Unless I am having a serious brainfart, it would not change your result because the OR condition will always be matched by the preceding chain of ANDs.

Comment: Ah, you're indeed right. It turns out our search failed because of a different reason. We use the search for a company list and one of the companies got the name "A & A *something more*". When we enter the search term A & A, it doesn't find it. I also just notice that it also doesn't find it when I just enter "&" as search term, so it seems the issue is somewhere else. I will make a new question for this and accept your answer for this one.

Comment: [Here is the new question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338943/iravenqueryablet-search-cant-find-sign-or-other-special-characters)